# Quicker show in explorer functionality

Tags: intellij-idea

When I need to find the location of a particular class I'm browsing I usually do:

ctrl + shift + a then choose "show in explorer".

But thats way too slow.

Is there any quick hotkey to get there immediately?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Main menu | Navigate | Select In... | Show in Explorer` - by default `Alt + F1 | some key`

Or simply map a shortcut to `Show in Explorer`